# PHP Heroku: how to add a subdirectory?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I'm trying to create an ajax sub-directory on my Heroku site.

The trouble is, I can't get it to work. I can go to https://myherokusite.com/images and https://myherokusite.com/stylesheets, but I can't get https://myherokusite.com/ajax to work - I get a 404 not found error!

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
//0.js
var params={
      type: "POST",
      url: "./ajax/getAllRanks.php",
      data: "",
       complete: function(xhr, status){
    var msg=xhr.responseText;
    var ranks=jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    addRanks2(ranks);
      }
    };
var result=$.ajax(params);
```

and I include `0.js` in my `index.php` as follows:

```
//index.php
<script src="./ajax.0.js"></script>
```

I simply cannot add a sub-directory to heroku.

Comment: Posting some code would be a nice start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a possible duplicate... You can get more information one the [git FAQ page](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F) or at the link below.

[How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)